# How to add licence /installation folder screen in javafx app

Tags: java, deployment, installation, inno-setup, licensing

I have created a JavaFx app in Windows 8.1+ NetBeans 8.2 and its installations works perfectly. However, it does not give any option of choosing destination folder or license agreement screen during installation. I tried adding licenceheader.txt on project properties and build the application but still it installs straight forward. So my question is how to add those things into my app?

EDIT: Used InnoSetup to create the .exe self contained installer.

Comment: I used InnoSetup to create the exe installer.

Comment: I think you should add the pertinent parts of the script to your question (or the whole script if it is not too long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `[Languages]` section you specify your license. Example:

```
[Languages]
Name: "English"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"; LicenseFile: "..\..\Inno\l.eng\LicenseEnglish.rtf"; InfoAfterFile: "..\..\Inno\l.eng\InfoAfterEnglish.rtf"
```

Make sure `DisableDirPage` is not set to `no`. Perhaps you can show your script so we can assist you properly with this.

[image: DisableDirPage]

Note that the default setting is `auto` and as indicated this means the window will **not be shown** if the same application is already installed. This is the usual behaviour. To force it to show then use a value of `no` as mentioned.

---

You can set these things using [Inno Script Studio](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio). For example:

[image: App Folder]

[image: Languages]

---

If you installed the [QuickStart Pack](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php#qsp) then it would have offered to install this IDE.

> The Inno Setup QuickStart Pack includes Inno Setup itself and additionally includes *an option to install the Inno Script Studio script editor*. This script editor is not official and is not required for general usage, but make Inno Setup easier to use. See the Third-Party Files page for more information.
>
> The Inno Setup QuickStart Pack also includes an option to download and install official encryption support.

---

## Clarification

As per the comments, for a *single-language* installer, use just [LicenseFile directive](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_licensefile) to `[Setup]` section. No need to introduce a dummy `[Languages]` section just to add a licence.

This can also be set using Inno Script Installer:

[image: Setup Options]